# What is the "Natural" Product Measure on $\mathbf{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, product-measure

It seems like most of the times when we talk about product measures $\mathbf{R}^n$, we are talking about Lebesgue measure on $\mathbf{R}^n$. I will denote this measure space as $(\mathbf{R}^n, \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}^n), m_{\mathbf{R}^n})$.

On the other hand, one may consider the canonical product measure on $\mathbf{R}^n$ defined as product of the measure spaces $(\mathbf{R}, \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}), m_{\mathbf{R}})$, namely, the measure space $(\mathbf{R}^n, \otimes_n \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}), \pi)$, where $\pi: \otimes_{n} \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}) \to [0, +\infty]$ is the product measure extended by the Catheodory Extension Theorem from the premeasure $\pi_0: \{ \bigcup_{finite} A_i \times B_i: A_i, B_i \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}) \} \to [0, +\infty]$.

At the beginning I thought it would make sense that we have $(\mathbf{R}^n, \otimes_n \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}), \pi) = (\mathbf{R}^n, \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}^n), m_{\mathbf{R}^n})$. However, I have not yet succeeded in proving the equality. In particular, I am stuck at showing
$$
\otimes_n \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}) = \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}^n).
$$
We can consider this in the case where $n = 2$ and conclude by induction. Now I believe it is true that
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}) \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}) \subseteq \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R^2})
$$
since the cartesian product of two Lebesgue measurable sets are measurable: [Is the product of two measurable subsets of $R^d$ measurable in $R^{2d}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360876/is-the-product-of-two-measurable-subsets-of-rd-measurable-in-r2d). I am not so sure about the converse inclusion:
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}^2) \subseteq \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R}) \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{R})
$$
Perhaps we need to argue through Borel $\sigma$-algebra and talk about the completion of measure spaces? Or is there a $\lambda$-$\pi$ system argument here? In fact, I fear this might not even be true. If this is not true, why do we introduce product measure as it is? What would be the motivation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inclusion $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2) \subseteq \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$ isn't true.  What is true is that $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the completion of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$.  Typically the product of two measure spaces will not be complete, even if the underlying measures are (see [Product of complete measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608857/product-of-complete-measures)).  Of course, you can always take the completion, if you wish.  Alternatively, you can restrict to the Borel sets, since $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.